# UDP packets from Raspberry Pi not received on Windows PC

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, udp, windows-11

I was trying to send UDP packets from my Pi to my Windows 11 PC. I wrote these two small scripts for troubleshooting:

Server: (Pi)

```
import socket
from time import sleep

_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
ip = '-->[The coresponding IP Adress]<--'
port = 4000
data = 'hello'.encode()
while True:
    _socket.sendto(data, (ip,port))
    sleep(.1)
```

Client: (PC)

```
import socket

_sockte = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
_sockte.bind(('',4000))
while True:
    pack = _sockte.recvfrom(1024)
    print(pack[0].decode())
```

When I ran this on both devices, the script on the PC wouldn't respond, but Wireshark clearly showed the packets being sent from the Pi to the PC on port 4000. Surprisingly it worked just fine when I ran the Server script on the PC and the Client script on the Pi.

I don't know what could be causing this issue, especially since I have done it before in the same way, however, this was on a different network with a different PC and Pi.

Edit (solved):

I solved the issue. It was the firewall blocking all incoming UDP packets because it considered my network as a public network. I changed the network type to Private and now the traffic is allowed.

Comment: They are packets (actually datagrams or messages) not "packages".  (Packages are things that the postman or courier leaves on your doormat.)

Comment: My guess that the problem is that a firewall or gateway or something is dropping the UDP messages.   But this is not a **programming** question.  You are better off asking on (say) ServerFault.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. PS. Im from germany amd we call packets packages (its the same word in german for both things) but thanks for the info